# Joins result is not correct php

Tags: php, join

i want to fetch data from two tables
i want to get fields services.service_name and services.detail.price where services id and services detail.services id match
right now i am using following query

```
SELECT services.service_name,services_detail.price FROM services
JOIN services_detail
ON services.id=services_detail.salon_id
WHERE services_detail.salon_id='1'
```

its showing price differently/correctly but showing only one service name.What is wrong with my query

here is my first table "services"

```
id              typeid          service_name            
1               1               Abc
2               1               xyz
3               1               why 
4               1               wxy
5               1               yxy
```

here is second table

table name  -   services_detail

```
id          salon_id        services_id         price
1           1               1                   70
2           1               2                   80
3           2               1                   45
4           2               4                   50
5           3               1                   70
```

Comment: Show the results as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have performed `JOIN` on an incorrect column.

Change `services_detail.salon_id` to `services_detail.services_id` in `ON` clause

```
SELECT services.service_name,services_detail.price FROM services
JOIN services_detail
ON services.id=services_detail.services_id
WHERE services_detail.salon_id='1'
```